# Strange error in mybatis mapper

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I have a simple select I wrote in a myBatis mapper:

```
<select id="listAllOrders" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" resultMap="commonMaps.detailedOrderResultMap">

    select

    <include refid="commonSql.fragmentOrderFields" />,
    <include refid="commonSql.fragmentSummaryPriceInfoFields" />

    from graorder order 
          left outer join grasummarypriceinfo summarypriceinfo on order.totalPrice_id = summarypriceinfo.id

    <if test="userGroupId != null">
        where order.userGroupId = #{userGroupId}
    </if>

    order by order_lastUpdated desc

    <if test="limit != null">
        limit #{limit}
    </if>

</select>
```

The complaining when running this query is:

```
 ### Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntax
ErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corr
esponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left oute
r join grasummarypriceinfo summarypriceinfo on order.totalPrice_id = su' at line
 33
```

I am simply discouraged. I can't see any error in my select...

Do you have any clue?

Comment: Does the query work outside of MyBatis and outside of JDBC?  If not, can you post what the final SQL you would use would look like?  If the SQL works in the mysql client, can you also get it to work with just JDBC, not using MyBatis? Need to narrow down whether this is a MySQL/SQL problem or something with the MyBatis mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the SQL keyword `order` as a table alias. That causes an error in MySQL.  For example, I just tried this query on one of my tables:

```
mysql> select order.film_id, order.title from film order 
       where order.film_id > 100 limit 4;
```

and got the same error:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where order.film_id > 100 limit 4' at line 1`

Comment: Wow...this is indeed the issue!